# Issues Reading an XML with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, xml-parsing

I am trying to read the following XML into my database on my mobile app.

```
     <RESPONSE>
       <IMAGERY_RESPONSE>
          <EMBEDDED_FILE _Type="JPEG" _EncodingType="BASE64" _ImageOrientation="Front" _Latitude="10" _Longitude="20">
            <DOCUMENT>animagebaseinbase64</DOCUMENT>
          </EMBEDDED_FILE>
          <EMBEDDED_FILE _Type="JPEG" _EncodingType="BASE64" _ImageOrientation="Side" _Latitude="11" _Longitude="21">
            <DOCUMENT>animagebaseinbase64</DOCUMENT>
          </EMBEDDED_FILE>
          <EMBEDDED_FILE _Type="JPEG" _EncodingType="BASE64" _ImageOrientation="Back" _Latitude="12" _Longitude="22">
            <DOCUMENT>animagebaseinbase64</DOCUMENT>
          </EMBEDDED_FILE>
       </IMAGERY_RESPONSE>
     <RESPONSE>
```

The issue I'm having is I only get 1 of the documents(the base64 encoded photo), from what I know the following jQuery function should be working correctly. Please let me know if any of you see anything off or that should be done a different way, I'm kind of new to jQuery.

```
    $(xml).find("RESPONSE").each(function () {
         $(this).find("IMAGERY_RESPONSE").each(function () {
              $(this).find("EMBEDDED_FILE").each(function () {
                   var long = $(this).attr('_Longitude').valueOf();
                   var lat = $(this).attr('_Latitude').valueOf();
                   var ori = $(this).attr('_ImageOrientation').valueOf();
                      $(this).find("DOCUMENT").each(function () {
                           var docu = $(this).valueOf();
                       })
                   photoToDatabase(long, lat, ori ,docu);
                })
            })
      });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should put semi-colon at the end of each line of code in Javascript.

Comment: BTW, `long` is a reserved word in Javascript, you must call your var another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(xml).find("RESPONSE").each(function () {
         $(this).find("IMAGERY_RESPONSE").each(function () {
              $(this).find("EMBEDDED_FILE").each(function () {
                   var long = $(this).attr('_Longitude');
                   var lat = $(this).attr('_Latitude');
                   var ori = $(this).attr('_ImageOrientation');
                   var docu;
                      $(this).find("DOCUMENT").each(function () {
                           docu = $(this).text();
                       })
                   photoToDatabase(long, lat, ori ,docu);
                })
            })
      });
```

Comment: Did you actually try this?  The changes you have made are correct, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well spotted.  It's obviously wrong, but it still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Bizarre - didn't want to work in the console for me.  Nicely done :)